# explicit require in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, require

I am converting my Rails 2 app to Rails 3. So far, I've been successful. However, there is this strange issue that I have to explicitly require any external files. Here is my original (i.e. Rails 2) ActiveRecord model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :translations, :dependent => :destroy
  include Freebase
...
end
```

in order to make it working in Rails 3, I have to require the model *Translation* and *Freebase.rb* file, thus:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/translation.rb')
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :translations, :dependent => :destroy
  require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '../../../lib/freebase.rb')
  include Freebase
  ...
end
```

Is it the normal way in Rails 3, or I am doing something wrong. In other words, why is it necessary to *explicitly* include those files? There might probably be some reason for the *Freebase.rb* file, which is placed in the *lib* folder, but what about the *Translation* model which is in the same dir?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 3 doesn't automatically autoload quite as much as Rails 2 did.

Open up config/application.rb and customize the line that looks like:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

In your case, you probably want to have

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What about the fact that I need to load the files of my models, too? Rails doesn't recognise JSON, too, even though it's built in. Funny stuff happening!

Comment: About JSON - it seems that I need to call it like so: `ActiveSupport::JSON` and it'd work.